# I would to display the PDF converted Image posted from one template to be displayed in other template

Tags: django, image, opencv, django-templates, django-views

Please help displaying this image. I am trying to convert python script to webservice.

Template index.html

```
<body>
{% block pagecontent %}
{{ form }}
<form  action="select.html" id="file-upload-form" class="modal-content animate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="uploadForm">

Select Files: <input type="file" name="myfile" required ></br> <span id=disp> </span>   <!-- <a href="/about/">Button</a> -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='upload-btn'> Upload File </button>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Template select.html

```
<div>
    {{context}}
    <img src="{{context}}" width="200" height="200">
  </div>
```

Apps urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', index),
url(r'^index', index),
url(r'^select', select),
]
```

Apps views.py

```
def index(request):
return render_to_response("index.html")


def select(request):
global response
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
    myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    img = pdf2image.convert_from_path(filename)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/png")
    for i,image in enumerate(img):
        image.save(response, "png")
    context = {'img':response}
    return render_to_response('select.html', context)
```

Terminal API responses.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 18, 2018 - 13:58:31
Django version 2.0.3, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[18/Mar/2018 13:58:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 796
[18/Mar/2018 13:59:25] "POST /select.html HTTP/1.1" 200 538
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a separate view that just returns the image:

```
from PIL import Image

def send_image(request):
   filename = requests.GET.get('file')
   fs = FileSystemStorage()
   if fs.exists(filename):
      try:
         image = pdf2image.convert_from_path(fs.path(filename))
         response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/png")
         image.save(response, "png")
         return response
      except:
         error_image = Image.new('RGBA', (1, 1), (255,0,0,0))
         response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
         error_image.save(response, "JPEG")
         return response
   else:
         error_image = Image.new('RGBA', (1, 1), (255,0,0,0))
         response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
         error_image.save(response, "JPEG")
         return response
```

Then call it like this, with the name of your PDF file.

```
<img src="/send_image?file=name_of_file.pdf" />
```

In your code, modify your `select` method:

```
def select(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        context = {'img':filename}
        return render_to_response('select.html', context)
```

Then finally your template:

```
<div>
    <img src="/send_image?file={{img}}" width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Burhan, I am finding hard time to figure out how urls.py should be. Kindly be generous in helping me figuring it out.